# Cypress How can I get length of API response data? Please see github link and image link

Tags: api, response, cypress

here is code and https://github.com/chkashif167/Partie.Tests/blob/master/cypress/integration/1profile/get-parties.counts.profile.spec.js and here is result of code https://www.screencast.com/t/ngRKLRYsc but I want compare 46 length with count of parties in UI `

```js
describe("Partie Counts Profile Page Test", () => {
  before(function() {
    cy.SignIn();
    cy.fixture("vars.json").as("vars");
  });

  it("Partie Counts", () => {
    const profileBtn = "div.actions--left > button > img";

    ///// I want to get lenght of the parties from the url response and want check with counts in UI
    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.get(profileBtn).click();
    cy.wait(1000);

    cy.request(
      "api/v1/room/getUserRooms/d23eef09-e4e1-455d-a74c-03dfc61bde11"
    ).then(response => {
      cy.log(response.body);
      assert.equal(response.status, 200);
      expect(response.body).to.not.be.null;
      cy.log(response.body.length);
      cy.get("div:nth-child(3) > span.quick-stat-figure").should("contain",response.body.length);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Successfully checked the length

```js
describe("Partie Counts Profile Page Test", () => {
  before(function() {
    cy.SignIn();
    cy.fixture("vars.json").as("vars");
  });

  it("Partie Counts", () => {
    const profileBtn = "div.actions--left > button > img";

    ///// I want to get lenght of the parties from the url response and want check with counts in UI
    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.get(profileBtn).click();
    cy.wait(1000);

    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      method: "GET",
      url: "api/v1/room/getUserRooms/d23eef09-e4e1-455d-a74c-03dfc61bde11"
    }).as("get_jobs");
    
    cy.wait("@get_jobs").then(xhr => {
      cy.log(xhr.response.body.length);
      cy.get("div:nth-child(3) > span.quick-stat-figure").should(
        "contain",
        xhr.response.body.length
      );
    });
  });
});
```